# Is it wrong to create a vue component for every svg icon?

Tags: vue.js, svg, nuxt.js

I like to use `inline svg` in my projects because it gives me great control over things like *width, height, fill color, stroke width and stroke color* using **css** and **js**(props). I usually create a vue.js SFC ([single file component](https://vuejs.org/guide/scaling-up/sfc.html#single-file-components)) for every SVG icon. Here's an example:

```html
<!-- IconsArrowRight.vue -->
<template>
  <svg
    viewBox="0 0 14 14"
    fill="currentColor"
    xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
  >
    <path
      d="M7.57026 0.888947L5.98842 2.46006L9.4199 5.89117L0.333374 5.89117L0.333374 8.10895H9.4199L5.98842 11.5401L7.57026 13.1112L13.6681 7.00006L7.57026 0.888947Z"
    />
  </svg>
</template>
```

And then I would use it like this (I'm using tailwindCSS for styling):

```html
<template>
  <div>
    <IconsArrowRight class="w-8 h-8 text-blue-500" />
  </div>
</template>
```

I use more than 50 icons in my project, and I've created a vue.js component for each one; Is it a bad practice regarding production performance to have so many components just for icons? Should I use font-icons instead, or any other alternative method?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using one `.vue` file for one `.svg` is totally fine IMO. It will not have any big impact performance-wise, just maybe take a bit longer when building your app but nothing that critical IMO.
Also, using it this way can have quite some flexibility in some [rare situations](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67296426/8816585) regarding HTML specification.

Now, regarding the best approach ever, I'd probably say to use [@unocss/preset-icons](https://github.com/unocss/unocss/tree/main/packages/preset-icons) or any package based on [Iconify](https://iconify.design/) simply because it will bring you all the available and imaginable icons on the fly, with no drawbacks and a LOT of flexibility + nice DX.
Here is [an article](https://antfu.me/posts/icons-in-pure-css) in 4 parts that will explain all the reasoning behind this approach and how it can be integrated universally to any solution (even if not using Antfu's solution).

Comment: Interesting _Journey on Icons_; there is also the 100% native Web Components way: https://iconmeister.github.io

Answer (score 2):

Most probably either using the svg as component or as font icon from performance side I would not consider any issue at all. Vue.js is a framework that can be used for large scale applications and your components are not heavy at all, they just use an SVG.

My personal preference would be to be used as font icons as you mentioned and use a component that you will be passing as props the font icon, so with this way you would have 1 component for all svgs.

About the styling, again using a prop to pass all the styles and bind that prop with the `:class`

This would be much cleaner I think,

Cheers

Comment: This removes the benefit of being able to quickly `ctrl + shift + p` towards a specific SVG file and debug/modify it tho.